# Why is UPDATE statement not working in SQL code?

Tags: sql

I am trying to update one row of the storeID column. When I do the first code below, it runs but will not affect any row. However, the bottom two are producing the following error " The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "Products_FK". The conflict occurred in database "group7", table "dbo.Products", column 'storeID'."

Could anyone help? Thanks!

[Table in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj5ZX.png)

```
UPDATE Store
SET storeID='E50'
WHERE storeID='D50'
AND storeID is Null;
```

```
UPDATE Store
SET storeID='E50'
WHERE storeID='D50'
```

```
UPDATE Store
SET storeID='E50'
WHERE storeName='A Plus Cables'
```

Above is the code that I have tried and nothing is being updated.

Comment: Does a storeID of 'E50' exist in your `products` table?

Comment: @ Ryan. No it doesn't. It is messed up in all the tables. Our professor switched around data after we had placed them in SQL.

Comment: Then that is why it is failing. The provided answer gives enough details to explain this, but as the answer states, since that column has reference to the product table and that key doesn't exist in products, it won't allow you to update it  to a value that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

The first one can't possibly match any rows, because a single value can't equal two different things at the same time:

```
WHERE storeID='D50'
AND storeID is Null
```

So that one is kind of a moot point.  You'd need to update the `WHERE` clause to target the record(s) you want to target.

For the latter two, the error is telling you what's wrong.  You're trying to write this value to a column:

```
SET storeID='E50'
```

But the error is telling you:

1. That column is a foreign key to another table. (`Products`?)
2. The value you're writing isn't presentin that other table.

So your options are:

1. Use a value that *is* present in the other table.
2. Use `NULL` (and update the column to allow `NULL` if necessary).
3. Remove the foreign key constraint to that other table.